# PHP SoapCall multiple elements

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to send a SOAP request that contains an element that repeats.

```
                        $params = array(
                        'UpdatedShipment' => array(
                            'OriginalShipDate'=>'2020-11-01',
                            'ShipmentInfo'=>array(
                                'Account' => 'XXXXX',
                                'ShipmentIdentificationNumber'=>'XXXXXXX',
                                'ServiceType'=>'P',
                                'PaperlessTradeEnabled'=>'1',
                                'SpecialServices'=>array(
                                    'Service'=>array(
                                        'ServiceType'=>'WY'
                                    )
                                ),
                                'IncludePreviousPieceLabels'=>'Y',
                                'DocumentImages'=> array(
                                    'DocumentImage'=>array(
                                        array('DocumentImageType'=>'INV','DocumentImage'=>base64_encode('xxxxxx'),'DocumentImageFormat'=>'PDF'),
                                        array('DocumentImageType'=>'DCL','DocumentImage'=>base64_encode('xxxxxx'),'DocumentImageFormat'=>'PDF'),
                                    )
                                ) 
                           ),
                        )
                    );
                    $result = $s->UpdateShipmentRequest((array)($params));
```

It throws an exception:
SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'DocumentImage' property

This is WSDL
https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/sndpt/updateShipment?WSDL

How can i resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: append wsdl link

Comment: And use wrappers like https://github.com/pwnlabs/nusoap and https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator to generates classes

Comment: This is wsdl
https://wsbexpress.dhl.com/sndpt/updateShipment?WSDL

Comment: I'm think problem in php extension, use objects instead arrays

Comment: Same error:
$result = $s->UpdateShipmentRequest($this->array_to_object($params));

array_to_object is a function that convert recursively array to std object class

Comment: no, u must use SoapParam & SoapVar + set classmap option at construct